# How do i reset v-money form fields

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my vuetify v-form i have fields to insert monetary values in which i use v-money to mask the values inserted, however when i try to reset the form, using either ".reset()" or by setting the values at the end of my function, the values are not reset.

What others way can i tr to reset the these fields?

The code is as follows

```
<v-col cols="6">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="value1" 
        v-money="money"
        refs='value1'
        :rules="baseRules"
        label="gross value"
    ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
<v-col cols="6" v-if='reset'>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="value2" 
        v-money="money"
        :rules="baseRules"
        label="net value"
    ></v-text-field>
</v-col>

data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    value1: '',
    value2: '',
    money: {
        decimal: ',',
        thousands: '.',
        prefix: '$ ',
        precision: 2,
        masked: false
    },
}),
methods: {
    reset () {
      this.$refs.myFormRef.reset()
      this.value1 = ''
      this.value2 = 0
    },
```

i also tried the following code but it didnt work.
https://codepen.io/mukatk/pen/NYZvPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v-money directive is not compatible with Vuetify's input I fear.

And it's worse than the reset issue. If you check your value you'll see it's actually the masked string (like "$ 123.456,01") instead of the number (123456.01).

Comment: yeah, i used an example which i'll link in the op but that didn't work either. or maybe i implemented it wrong when i tried it.

Comment: maybe it is something related to the $ref since my for componente has a ref and my field has another ref

Comment: My example was wrong because I didn't actually load the directive properly. Since v-money wasn't active there was no issue :p I Updated my answer

Comment: yeah so i dont really know what to do here. maybe i'll change libraries. are there an other vuetify friendly mask libraries?

Comment: Those should work I think: https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/ if you want all sort of masks or https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/ for only currency

Comment: vue-the mask was the one that recommended v-money